# VHDL: component port to entity port, how does it know what is what?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

```
entity Adder4Bit is
Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       S : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       COUT : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Adder4Bit;

architecture structure of Adder4Bit is

component FullAdder -- add the fulladder to this architecture
port (
        A       : in std_logic;
        B       : in std_logic;
        CIN : in std_logic;
        SUM : out std_logic;
        COUT    : out std_logic
        );
end component;

signal wires : std_logic_vector(3 downto 1) := "000";       -- Make a signal "wires" with initial value 000

begin

adder0 : FullAdder port map ( A=> A(0), B => B(0), CIN => '0', SUM => S(0), COUT => wires(1)        );
adder1 : FullAdder port map ( A=> A(1), B => B(1), CIN => wires(1), SUM => S(1), COUT => wires(2)   );
adder2 : FullAdder port map ( A=> A(2), B => B(2), CIN => wires(2), SUM => S(2), COUT => wires(3)   );
adder3 : FullAdder port map ( A=> A(3), B => B(3), CIN => wires(3), SUM => S(3), COUT => COUT       );


end structure;
```

In adder3 at the very bottom, how do the program know what cout belongs to the entity Adder4Bit and what cout belongs to the component FullAdder? 
Does it have anything to do with the direction of the arrow?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, the left side is the name inside the component, and the right side is the name of you vhdl signal.

It's the same way it knows that the left B is std_logic while the right one is the std_logic_vector.

Answer (score 2):

The left hand side is a "pin name" and the right hand side is a "wire name" - so these two:

```
adder2 : FullAdder port map ( A=> A(2), B => B(2), CIN => wires(2), SUM => S(2), COUT => wires(3)   );
adder3 : FullAdder port map ( A=> A(3), B => B(3), CIN => wires(3), SUM => S(3), COUT => COUT       );
```

`adder2`'s `COUT` pin connects to the signal called `wires(3)` and `adder3`'s `COUT` pin connects to the signal called `COUT`.

This is one of the problem with having pins and signals named the same thing - keep at it and you'll not even notice thinking about it in a week or so!